# Downloading tweets with twitteR in R, some tweets are cut short, any way to get full tweets?

Tags: r, twitter

I am using twitteR package for R to download tweets from particular timelines, including retweets. The thing is, some retweets are cut short.

For example, I am downloading Donald Trump's tweets and he has retweeted this tweet: https://twitter.com/SecretarySonny/status/906666266320146432

I get this when downloading from Trump's timeline:
"RT @SecretarySonny: Serious @Cabinet meeting today, called by @POTUS at Camp David. Reports on #Irma's track, potential impact, fed & state…"

When the full text is:
 "Serious @Cabinet meeting today, called by @POTUS at Camp David. Reports on #Irma's track, potential impact, fed & state **preparedness.**"

It seems that the tweets are cut short by the number of characters required to spell name of the original Twitter account (SecretarySonny in this case).

Is there any way I could get the full retweets? I checked twitteR documentation but I was not able to find anything that could help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `?tweet_mode=extended` parameter when you call the Twitter API. This is covered in the [extended Tweets documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets) on Twitter's developer site. What code are you currently using?

Comment: Can't believe I asked this question almost 2 months ago and left it hanging here. Argh! I wanted to thank you for taking time to help. I have been using `rtweet` package for R and it seems that the problem may be in the package itself.  In the end, I decided not to use retweets in my analysis for unrelated reasons, so the problem solved itself in a way.